# Symfony - Set Sonata Admin filter operator to "is equal to" as default option

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

In sonata admin I have a working filter in my admin class:

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('client.name');
}
```

The filter will default to match "contains" (LIKE operator) like this:

[image]

I would like the filter to use "is equals to" (= operator) as the default option instead of "contains":

[image]

Unfortunately I couldn't find questions or answers related to this in SO, google, and the [Sonata docs 9.4 
filters](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/action_list.html#filters) is currently not documented.

How can I do this?

Comment: I am curious too because I really could use this... I tried it out but couldn't find a way neither...

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't found how to do this. It is not critical for my application at this time. I'll post if I find anything.

Answer (score 1):

I did it with JQuery:

```
////This function is used for settings all the filter
////in the default views
$("select").find("option").each(function() {
    var ArrayClasses = $(this).parent().attr('class').split(' ');
    var IsFilter = false;
    $.each(ArrayClasses, function(i, value){
        if (value === 'sonata-filter-option')
            IsFilter = true;
    });
    if ($(this).val() === '3' && IsFilter) {
        var HtmlStr = "<span class='select2-chosen'>is iqual to</span>" +
                      "<abbr class='select2-search-choice-close'></abbr>" +
                      "<span class='select2-arrow'><b></b></span></a>";
        $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
        var WrapId = $(this).parent().prev().attr('id');
        $("#" + WrapId + " a.select2-choice").html(HtmlStr);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override default filter options by overriding the variable `$datagridValues`

```
protected $datagridValues = array(
        'email' => array(
            'type' => 3,
            'value' => ''
        )
    );
```

`'type' => 3` means its `equal to`

Answer (score 0):

Post after a long time. You can override default filter options by overriding the variable `$datagridValues`

```
protected $datagridValues = array(
        'email' => array(
            'type' => 3,
            'value' => ''
        )
    );
```

`'type' => 3` means its `equal to`